# Get right images size

Tags: jquery, css

How to get right image size after CSS3 scale has been applied?

Comment: You mean the dimensions of the image before CSS3 scale (which might have width and height set), or the intrinsic dimensions of the image file itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you've scaled it by, reverse calculate it.

I'm guessing you don't. in that case do something like: (brief example)

```
($(this).css("-moz-transform:"));
```

extract the value and multiply by the style width & height.